# Calling super Method within Anonymous Class

Tags: java, inheritance

What is the proper way to call the super method of ParentClass from an anonymous class?

In its current state super is referring to the Runnable.

```
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {

    @Override
    public void myMethod(final double value) {

        new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.myMethod(value);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    @Override
    public void myMethod(final double value) {
        new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ChildClass.super.myMethod(value);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Kind of seems like it should cause an infinite loop, but then again looks good.

Comment: If you use `ChildClass.this.myMethod(value)` it will cause an infinite loop.

Answer (score 5):

call  `ChildClass.super.myMethod(value);`

**Note** : You can also use `ChildClass.this.myAttribute` / `ChildClass.this.myMethod()` if you want to access instance attributes/methods from `ChildClass`.